# Obtaining inconsistent results in Spark

Tags: pyspark

Have any Spark experts had strange experience: obtaining inconsistent map-reduce results using pypark?

Suppose in the midway, I have a RDD

```
....
add = sc.parallelize([(('Alex', item1), 3), (('Joe', item2), 1),...])
```

My goal is to aggregate how many different users, so I do

```
print (set(rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0][0],1)).reduceByKey(add).collect()))
print (rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0][0],1)).reduceByKey(add).collect())
print (set(rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0][0],1)).reduceByKey(add).map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()))
```

These three prints should have the same content (though in different formats). For example, the first one is a set of `set({('Alex', 1), ('John', 10), ('Joe', 2)...})`; second a list of `[('Alex', 1), ('John', 10), ('Joe', 2)...]`. The number of the items should be equal to the number of different users. Third is a `set({'Alex', 'John', 'Joe'...})`

But instead I got `set({('Alex', 1), ('John', 2), ('Joe', 3)...})`; second a list of `[('John', 5), ('Joe', 2)...]`('Alex' is even missing here). The lengths of the set and list are different.

Unfortunately, I even cannot reproduce the error if I only write a short test code; still get right results. Did any meet this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out.
The reason is that if I used the same RDD frequently, I need to `.cache()`.
If the RDD becomes

```
add = sc.parallelize([(('Alex', item1), 3), (('Joe', item2), 1),...]).cache()
```

then the inconsistent problem solved.

Or, if I further prepare the aggregated rdd as

```
aggregated_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0][0],1)).reduceByKey(add)
print (set(aggregated_rdd.collect()))
print (aggregated_rdd.collect())
print (set(aggregated_rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()))
```

then there are no inconsistent problems neither.

Comment: I can imagine that caching insures that the results stay consistent but it does not insure that the results are correct.